# Transforming XML in the XML data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called tags, which looks like this:

```
 --------------------
|TagId   |   TagName |
--------------------
| 1      |   Travel  |
 --------------------
| 2      |   Gadgets |
 --------------------
| 3      |   Hobbies |
 --------------------
| 4      |   Movies  |
 --------------------
```

And I have another table, which has an XML data type column called Tags.

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |PostId   |   Title          | Tags                                       |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | 1       |  Blog Post 1     | <xml><tags><tag>1</tag/><tag>2</tag></tags>|
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | 2       |  Blog Post 2     | <xml><tags><tag>2</tag/><tag>3</tag></tags>|
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | 3       |  Blog Post 3     | <xml><tags><tag>3</tag/><tag>4</tag></tags>|
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to combine the data from these two tables, to create a single view, which looks like this. The number inside the  node should act as a foreign key, to the Tags table.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Title         | Tags                                                      |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Blog Post 1   | <xml><tags><tag>Travel</tag/><tag>Gadgets</tag><tags>     |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Blog Post 2   | <xml><tags><tag>Gadgets</tag/><tag>Hobbies</tag></tags>   |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Blog Post 3   | <xml><tags><tag>Hobbies</tag/><tag>Movies</tag></tags>    |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to create a view like this? How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
/* SQL Follows */
select
postID, title,
tags,
(
    select 
        /* 4. Retrieve the tag name */
        y.tag.value('.', 'int') tagID,
        t.tagName
    from 
        /* 2. Shred the XML into nodes */
        p.tags.nodes('/xml/tags/tag') as y(tag)
        /* 3. Join the tag ID onto the tags table. */
        inner join #tags t on t.tagID = y.tag.value('.', 'int')
    for 
        /* 5. Convert it into XML */
        xml path('tag'), type
)tags2
/* 1. For each post */
from #posts p
```

I've used temp tables `#tags` and `#posts` in this example. To get the exact output you are after you will need to tweak the XML a little.

Comment: This almost works!! Only one problem that i noticed, is that the resultant XML schema is not quiet the way i wanted. The result is in the format

<tag>
  <tagName>Travel</tagName>
</tag>
<tag>
  <tagName>Gadgets</tagName>
</tag>

I want only one parent <tag> node.

Comment: As per the documentation, you can use `"text()"` to write a straight text node, so if you change it to `t.tagName as "text()"` and get rid of `tagID` that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well I won’t provide a full solution because I don’t know how  is your data. I’m sure it isn’t as simple as you displayed, but I think I can point you in the right direction.

I would do a replace on your full string, looking for ID (don’t look just for 1, because you can have 11 for example and that would fail) and then replace it by a select where tagID=ID

```
select replace('<xml><tags><tag>1</tag/><tag>2</tag></tags>','<tag>1</tag/>',(select name from tags where tagid=1))
```

result:

```
<xml><tags>Travel<tag>2</tag></tags>
```

of course, you would need to do this to each tag, than it is up to you how to do it. You could loo the tag table or if you have just a few tags, run the replace a few times

Comment: This is a string operation, and would require processing for each row. I am looking for some XML transformation to get the data. There has to be some mechanism that does that.